# Is there a way to mute all sound coming from a program?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to mute all sound coming from a program?

For example a program is producing some sound, and another one is, and I only want one of the programs muted.  And let's say the program that produces the sound doesn't have a control to mute or control the sound that comes from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the Sound icon in the traybar and start the Volume Mixer.

You will see all the sound sources listed, along with a master volume for the sound
device. You can set the sound level for each sound source, or totally mute it by
clicking on its sound icon at the bottom.

[image]